# Valid Regex for string with few special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am stuck with a regex check in javascript and can't find a valid solution for it.

My Javascript Function:

```
function checkFilledText() {
    var retBool = false;
    var vals= $("#input1").val();
    if ($.trim(vals) == "" || vals.length <= 0) {
        alert("No text entered");
        return false;
    }
    var pattrn = new RegExp("[A-Za-z0-9.\-/:]{3,15}");
        retBool = pattrn.test(vals);
    alert("Validation is: " + retBool);
}
```

The regex should validate `M-24554-236` while invalidate `M-45455^455`. This means that any string containing text (alphanumeric) with/without special chars including `/\.:-` anywhere in between is valid while any special chars other than that with alphanumeric should invalidate the string.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqa6Lszg/1/) . This fiddle currently validates both of them, while [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) says it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using a regex constructor, you need to escape some of the special characters so either use a regex like

```
var pattrn = /^[A-Z\d.\\\-\/:]{3,15}$/i
```

or

```
var pattrn = new RegExp("^[A-Z\\d.\\\\\\-\\/:]{3,15}$", 'i');
```

```js
function checkFilledText() {
  var retBool = false;
  var vals = $("#input1").val();
  if ($.trim(vals) == "" || vals.length <= 0) {
    $('#log').html("No text entered");
    return false;
  }
  var pattrn = new RegExp("^[A-Z\\d.\\\\\\-\\/:]{3,15}$", 'i');
  // M-2344234-234 must be valid
  // M%2344234-234 must be invalid
  retBool = pattrn.test(vals);
  $('#log').html("Validation is: " + retBool);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
<input type="submit" onclick="checkFilledText()" />

<div id="log"></div>
```